# How to bind ng-content to property?

Tags: angular

I want to bind ng-content to child component property. Is it possible?
For example for `<myComponent>123</myComponent>` MyComponent.content should be set to 123.

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: 'myComponent'
})
class MyComponent {
  content;          // should be set to 123
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  directives: [MyComponent],
  template: `
    <myComponent>123</myComponent>
  `
})
export class App { }
```

Comment: Binding implies that the value (`123` in your example) can change, and the value of property `content` would get automatically updated with any new values.  Are you really looking for a binding solution, or do you just want to extract the text or HTML (as Günter shows in his answer)?  (Please reword your title if you don't want binding.)

Comment: Günter saved my day. But the binding solution would be great also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: 'myComponent'
})
class MyComponent {
  content;          // should be set to 123

  constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) {
    this.content = this.elementRef.nativeElement.innerHTML;
  }

  // to ensure bindings have been resolved
  // see also 
  // https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#aftercontent
  afterContentChecked() {
    this.content = this.elementRef.nativeElement.innerHTML;
  }
}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/eJIVvT?p=preview)

Comment: Doesn't work with ngFor: `<myComponent *ngFor="#m of messages">{{m}}</myComponent>`

Comment: `{{m}}` is resolved later. Move the code in the directive from the constructor to `ngAfterViewInit(){...}`.

Answer (score 3):

If you need binding – i.e., the value `123` can change – and you want the directive to pick up any changes, implement [lifecycle hook `ngAfterContentChecked()`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#aftercontent):

```ts
@Directive({selector: 'myComponent'})
export class MyComponent {
  content:string;
  constructor(private _elRef: ElementRef) {}
  ngAfterContentChecked() {
     this.content = this._elRef.nativeElement.textContent; 
        // or maybe innerHTML, depending on what you want
     console.log('new value:', this.content);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<myComponent>{{number}}</myComponent>
     <button (click)="number = number + 1">increment</button>
     <button (click)="0">do nothing event</button>
     <br>look at console log for directive binding updates`,
  directives: [MyComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
  number = 123;
  constructor() { console.clear(); }
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GFVASzrBo4HjIB8scgHy?p=preview)</kbd>

Note that ngAfterContentChecked() is called every time change detection runs.  So only use this approach if you really need binding.

Comment: What about Query(TextDirective)? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Query-var.html

Comment: @Dizzy, Query() has been deprecated by ContentChild() and ContentChildren().  Both require a directive name, a component name, or a local template variable name to be passed in as an argument.  Since in your example your example you only have `123`, and hence no directive, component or local template variable (i.e., you do not have something like `<span #localTempVar>123</span>`) I did not use ContentChild.  If you did, e.g., use a local template variable, then you could also do it this way: `ContentChild('localTempVar') _elRef:ElementRef`.

Comment: The problem is when i set InnerHTML, the shadow dom becomes wrong and I cannot use DynamicComponentLoader to render child components in runtime. So i guess i should use {{text}} to render back changed value.